# Ran git rebase origin/develop and now I have a (develop|REBASE 1/2) - branch

Tags: git, rebase

So, I am still fairly new to git and still running into things here and there. Someone shared a quick tip for pulling on master branch... `git rebase origin/master`. So, I did the same on develop not thinking it would hurt it. Not I am at branch `(develop|REBASE 1/2)`. And when I switch to master it still shows `(develop|REBASE 1/2)`. I went to revert backwards a commit and nothing happened.

I am trying to undo this and get back to the latest commit.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

***EDIT***
So, I finally found something to help. I first ran `git rebase --abort`, then I really needed to go backwards so I ran `git reset --hard HEAD@{22}` to go back to the last commit I needed to before messing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rebase --abort` will cancel the rebase operation on the branch you currently have checked out.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: ...and will delete all uncommited changes. Very unwise.